# In text, does 'enumerate' imply a numbered list?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs, numbers, lists

(as in, say,

> Let me enumerate all the reasons red is my favorite colour, from most compelling to least:
>
> 1. it is the colour of blood
> 2. it works well with white
> 3. it comes first in RGB
>
> and that is about it.

)

And if so, is there a similarly-formed verb meaning 'to state all of the things in a category in an unordered list'?

My first thought was 'enlist', but obviously that already has a different meaning. Just 'list' comes close, but to me does not imply completeness.

Comment: It implies a list, but not necessarily a numbered one. You could easily have  "Let me enumerate the reasons red is my favorite colour, from most compelling to least: it is the color of blood, it works well with white, and it comes first in RGB." It does work well with numbers, however.

Comment: So is the 'numer' root just incidental to the meaning, then? If this is the case, submit it as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: Originally *enumerate* meant to count (Latin) but the meaning has broadened in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Merriam Webster’s page on [**enumerate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerate):

> **1**:  to ascertain the number of**:** Count
>
> **2**:  to specify one after another**:** List

Also from Merriam Webster’s page on enumerate

> Despite its numer- root, you don't have to use numbers when enumerating.

Based on the information provided by the dictionary’s page on the word, I can only conclude that you can enumerate your reasons without using numbers or giving the impression that you’re relying on a numbered list.

I would urge you to take a look at the Merriam Webster’s page on the said word.

Comment: Thank you. Especially useful was the thesaurus section, which I ought to have consulted before posting because of course synonyms often have welcome variation:

detail, itemize, list, numerate, recite, reel off, rehearse, tick (off)

outline; tabulate, tally; catalog (or catalogue), inventory; chart, diagram, graph; calculate, compute, estimate, figure, reckon; cite, mention, name